# Multi-page form validation using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am tasked to build a multi step form for a programming exercise and I have been having some trouble with the transistion to the next page, along with keeping the form valid. I am using the jQuery validate() plugin.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <form class="app-form">
                <fieldset id="time-info">
                    <h2 class="title">Submit Timesheet</h2>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Enter a valid email address." required></input><br><br>

                    <textarea type="textarea" name="text" class="message" placeholder="Message (optional)"></textarea>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="work">
                        <label>What type of work is this for?</label><br><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="vfx" name="work">
                        <label for="vfx">Time working on visual effects for a movie</label>
                        <br><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="review" name="work">
                        <label for="review">Time spent reviewing work of a junior artist</label>
                        <br><br>
                    </div>

                    <button class="clear button" type="reset" value="Clear">CLEAR</button>
                    <button class="next button" type="submit" value="Next">NEXT</button>
                </fieldset>

                 <fieldset id="submitted">
                    <h2 class="title">Timesheet Submitted</h2>
                    <p>Good job</p>
                </fieldset>

            </form>
```

And here is my Javascript. I first check if the form is valid, and then transition to the next fieldset. Although the problem is that my second fieldset doesn't show when I hit the next button, it instead just adds a query string to the URL. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(document).ready( function() {

    var form=$(".app-form");

    $('input,textarea').focus(function()
    {
        $(this).attr('placeholder','');

    });
    $('input,textarea').blur(function()
    {
        $(this).attr('','placeholder');

    });

    if( form.valid() ){
        $(".next").click(function(){
            if(animating) return false;
            animating = true;

            current_fs = $(this).parent();
            next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

            //show the next fieldset
            next_fs.show();
            //hide the current fieldset with style
            current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
                step: function(now, mx) {
                    //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
                    //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
                    scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
                    //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
                    left = (now * 50)+"%";
                    //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
                    opacity = 1 - now;
                    current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
                    next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
                },
                duration: 800,
                complete: function(){
                    current_fs.hide();
                    animating = false;
                },
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(".next").click(function(){...` registers a click handler for the `.next` button. You should perform the validity check inside the click handler, not wrap the assignment of the handler to the button inside a validation check.

Comment: I fixed that, although there is still something wrong. Even if I replace form.valid() with 'true' the second fieldset isn't shown.

Comment: Try making a jsfiddle or JSBin, or edit your question to include a StackOverflow snippet, that replicates the problem. It's much easier to troubleshoot these things if we can see the execution.